# Operator in terms of partial derivatives

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, complex-analysis, differential-geometry

Consider
$T: C^\infty(\mathbb{R}^2) \to C^\infty(\mathbb{R}^2), \quad T(f) := \dfrac{1}{1- (f_{xx} + \lambda f_{yy})^2}.$
Anyone knows which operator is this? It looks so familiar to me.